# Why are eigenvalues of nilpotent matrices equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

If $A$ is a $ \displaystyle  10 \times 10 $ matrix such that $A^{3} = 0$ but $A^{2}  \neq 0$ (so A is nilpotent) then I know that $A$ is not invertible, but why does at least one eigenvalue of $A$ have to be equal to zero? How would one show that all eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to zero?

Comment: Conceptually, it's because the matrix is collapsing that dimension down irreversibly.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If $v$ is a non-zero eigen vector corresponding to an eigenvalues $\lambda$ we have, by definition, $Av=\lambda v$. Then $A^2v= A( Av)= A(\lambda v)= \lambda^2v$. It easily follows that $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue for $A^n$ but the latter is the zero matrix, for which all eigenvalues are zero,   hence $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed.  5 up-votes in 27 seconds!

Comment: Travis, you are right. But I wrote the words "all eigenvalues are zero" for the zero matrix, thinking it requires no justification. However disregarding nilpotency if $B=p(A)$, with $p$ a polynomial, then it is true that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $f(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue for $B$.

Comment: eigenvectors are by definition nonzero.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Yes, see my comment above. Your latter statement is not true, however: If we take $A := -I$, $p(x) := x^2$, then $B = P(A) = I$ but $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ whereas $p(1) = 1$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.

Comment: @Travis: thanks for enlightening me and pointing out my mistake in the comment with an (embarrassingly) simple example.

Comment: Ah I see thanks, that makes a lot of sense! Does that mean A can be diagonalized?

Comment: @David: think about it. If it can be diagonalized what can be that diagonal matrix?

Comment: @PVanchinathan Yes, it seems it's a good morning for mistakes if my (now-erased) comment is any indication! :) I think the statement one wants is that if $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, in particular counting multiplicity, then $\lambda_1^n, \ldots, \lambda_k^n$ are the eigenvalues of $A^n$ counting multiplicity, and (since there are $n$ eigenvalues in the list) this accounts for all of the eigenvalues of $A^n$.

Answer (score 16):

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the nilpotent matrix $A,$ and $u$ its associated eigenvector. Then $$Au = \lambda u, u \neq 0$$ multiplying by $A$ on the right shows $$A^2u = \lambda Au = \lambda^2 u$$ and by induction $$A^n u = \lambda^n u$$

If $A$ is nilpotent, then $A^k = 0$ for some $k>0.$  that implies $\lambda^k = 0\to \lambda = 0.$

Comment: I stuck with the induction.

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively, do the contrapositive. If $A$ has a non-zero eigenvalue, $\lambda,$ then $A^{k} \neq 0 $ for all $k.$

Proof:
there exists $v \neq 0,$ such that 
$$
Av = \lambda v,
$$
so
$$
A^{k} v = \lambda^{k} v \neq 0.
$$
Done.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n$ is the smallest integer for which $A^n=0$. Since $A$ is non-zero $\implies$ $n \gt 1$

let the characteristic polynomial for $A$ be

$$
A^m+c_1A^{m-1}+\cdots + c_m = 0
$$
here $m \le n$. multiplying the equation by $A^{n-1}$ gives
$$
c_mA^{n-1} =0
$$
hence $c_m=0$. this procedure can be repeated to show that all coefficients except the first are zero, hence the equation is simply:
$$
A^m=0
$$
and we must have $m=n$

since the eigenvalues are roots of the equation:
$$
x^m = 0
$$
it follows that they must all be zero

Comment: I think $n$ should be greater than $1$ (first line of your post). How do you assure $m \leq n$, i.e. how do exclude the case $m \gt n$?