# Finding the determinant of A nilpotent matrix

Tags: matrices

Let B be a nilpotent n×n matrix with complex entries. Set A = B- I.  Find the determinant of A. 
Please someone give a hint..

Answer (score 1):

Nilpotent matrices have all eigenvalues being equal to zero [(see here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265679/why-are-eigenvalues-of-nilpotent-matrices-equal-to-zero).  So, for any eigenvector $v_i$ of $B$ we have that $Bv_i = \vec 0$.  Note that $B = A+I$, so we can write that $Av_i+Iv_i = \vec 0\implies A v_i = -v_i$.  This holds for any eigenvector $v_i$, so it follows that each eigenvalue of $A$ is $-1$.  The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, so $$\operatorname{det}A = \prod_{i = 1}^n\lambda_i = (-1)^n$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking to solve it with the expansion of $(B- I)^n$, so got confused. Eigenvalues method is much revealing.